# how to automatically generate a Module from a project in Visual Studio

Tags: fortran, visual-studio-2019, intel-fortran

I work with Fortran projects in VS2019. My projects employ many subroutines. I've been advised to put the subroutines into a MODULE to get more help from the debugger and code check. Copying the names of all the subroutines into a file (the module file) is a chore. Is there a way to automate this?

Furthermore, a VS project usually includes files that are in more than one folder. The MODULE seems to want all the files to be in the same folder or at least wants a full directory path, then the name of the folder. How can I avoid this hassle?

So, I put all the files in the same folder. The first procedure listed in the Module is `BUILDDAMAGEDLAMINATEBENDINGSTIFFNESSANDCTEI`

I got this error:

> error #6645: The name of the module procedure conflicts with a name in the encompassing scoping unit.   [BUILDDAMAGEDLAMINATEBENDINGSTIFFNESSANDCTEI]

I think the encompassing scoping unit is the main program, and there I call a subroutine with that name. What is wrong with that?

Comment: PS consider upgrading VS

Comment: should email this guy https://people.sissa.it/~aboiardi/post/fortran-on-windows/#code-with-modules-in-separate-files and direct him to this question!

Comment: Please show your code. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I do not understand this: "Copying the names of all the subroutines into a file (the module file) is a chore." What **exactly** are you doing? You should not really be copying "the names of the subroutines" anywhere. You should move the subroutines into the modules completely.

Comment: The encompassing scope of a module procedure is the module containing the module procedure.